# Economy / Tourism R and T - Cabin Baggage

Tags: luggage

I bought tickets for an in Europe flight via an online tour operator and got Economy / Tourism R and Economy / Tourism T as fares

The airline company clearly states there is not checked in baggage so I bought one piece as extra but what's not clear is about the carry on / cabin baggage: in addition to the actual baggage piece (the one up to 8kg)
it is also said a small personal item (e.g. handbag, ...) up to 3kg is included but for the Economy Light

Unfortunately it is not clear to me if any of my fares is Economy Light, from researchers it does not seem so but that's something certainly not clear to me

Is it anything standardized or company specific ?

If it is standardized, could you suggest a website that clearly explains this ?

Comment: It would probably help if you mentioned which airline you are travelling with, as they often have different definitions.

Comment: Right, it is Czech Airlines

Answer (score 1):

The fare classes are defined separately by each carrier, so there is not much to say *in general* based on your letters.

The airlines don't even advertise much what their letters mean. If you have a booking reference, your best chance at real information would be to use that to log into the airline's website (most have a "find my booking" facility) and see if you can get that to tell you what the precise baggage rules for it are.